# TabPanel KendoUi, AngularJs, Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

are there an alternative for Extjs TabPanel in Kendo Ui, AngularJs or Jquery?

[TabPanel Extjs demo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel)

Comment: Well, yes, kendo has a tab panel (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index) and there are lots of juqery options out there. https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @SteveGreene : they are similar to extjs tabpanel!!!!!!!!!!!